# NFT Minting failing on Localhost / MPL Metadata (solana-test-validator with meta clone)

Tags: anchor, metaplex, solana-test-validator, mpl-token-metadata

I'm running a local test validator via:

```
solana-test-validator --ledger=".anchor/test-ledger" --clone="metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s" --url="https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
```

But running my local NFT minting with Metadata fails locally (works on DevNet).

```
    'Program log: Instruction: MintTo',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4538 of 130977 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: invalid account data for instruction',
```

And have cloned the MetaPlex Metadata contract (see above). Do I need to initialise it somehow? As explorer.solana locally says it's not executable unlike the devnet version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found a better solution:

https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/accounts-and-data/fork-programs-to-localnet

Basically instead of --clone, dump the file from mainnet locally:

`solana program dump -u m metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s .anchor/metaplex.so`

Then Load using:

`solana-test-validator -r --bpf-program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s .anchor/metaplex.so`

Comment: Oh nice trick, thanks for sharing!